# How to change body style "pointer-events" to "auto" whenever OverLay is shown in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: vaadin, overlay, pointer-events

Many components, such as Dialog, MenuBar, ComboBox, DatePicker, TimePicker and etc, use an ovverlay when it is opened. For example, when a menu item is clicked, menu is shown, and an overlay is added to the document. Style "pointer-events:none;" is added to body to prevent interaction.

[image]
Is there any way to change the style "pointer-events" to "auto" ("pointer-events:auto;")? We are using Vaadin 14.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change/override property pointer-event in a Vaadin dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76406281/how-to-change-override-property-pointer-event-in-a-vaadin-dialog)

Comment: This is a more generic question. We are looking for generic solution.

Comment: It would help to get answer to your question if you would explain why? What you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: There's an open enhancement ticket here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/5417